comparative/ noun/ a more intelligent girl than
a. Sally is a more intelligent girl than Tom.
b. Sally is a more intelligent girl than Tom is.
Do those imply that Tom is a girl?
Even if from a strictly logical standpoint they do, don't people use such sentences in real life regardless of whether Tom is a girl on not?
Many thanks

My intuition insists that A is better than B, but I can't think of a single logical difference.

Yes, they both imply Tom is a girl, as well as being less intelligent than Sally. "Intelligent" and "girl" are modifying the same thing. No, English speakers would omit "girl", if Tom isn't one.

It doesn't necessarily imply that Tom' a girl. "Tom" is a boy's name 99.99% of the time in Anglophone countries, so the utterance is an outlier statistically. It is odd. It could actually be pointing out in context the fact that Tom is indeed not a girl and doing so in a  humorous way. The stereotype is that girls have more "emotional intelligence" than boys. Sally might have picked up on the cues of the situation where Tom had been obtuse. Tom's mom might have wondered out loud why Tom had been so slow, and Sally's mom could say "Well, Sally is a more intelligent girl than Tom."

And if all you're comparing is intelligence, it's misleading to mention gender, just as when comparing the height of two skyscrapers it would be a form of miscommunication to say "A is a taller hotel than B" if both buildings are not hotels.  People tend not to make such miscommunication errors.   But to assume that the utterance implies something implies that the listener infers, but what the listener might think is that the speaker is an oddball.  It would depend on the context and the actors involved.

Will you re-phrase 'comparative/ noun/ a more intelligent girl than' so it at least has the form of a question, or means something in English, if not both?
Either way, what makes you think people use such sentences in real life? Can you cite several examples? Three or four, say?
Both examples necessarily imply, either Tom is a girl or the speaker isn't much worried about correct English, or both.
'… than Tom is…' strikes me as more likely to make that problem worse than to clarify anything.
Either way, it clearly makes the Question worse.

Both examples have Tom as a girl.
(a) has Tom in the object case.
(b) has an ellipsis:

b. Sally is a more intelligent girl than Tom is (an intelligent girl).

and I'd use this version, that is, with is.
If Tom isn't a girl, I'd say

Sally is a more intelligent person than Tom is (an intelligent person).


Sally is more intelligent than Tom is (intelligent).

This listing of the phrases  more intelligent than he shows that the phrase usually has
some variations of BE or linking verbs following it either directly or after some adverbs.

OP's query


Sally is a more intelligent girl than Tom.
Sally is a more intelligent girl than Tom is.
Do those imply that Tom is a girl?


Also consider this sentence
3. Sally is more intelligent  than Tom.
"Sentences 1 and 2 imply Tom is a girl because they compare 'a more intelligent girl' between Sally and Tom.
In contrast, Sentence 3 (Sally is more intelligent than Tom) simply compares their intelligence without specifying gender.
While Sentence 3 is common, I haven't come across Sentence 1 and 2, which is incorrect if Tom is a boy. (correct if she is a tomboy)
